# Virtualizing Windows 7 x64 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, 64-bit

Is Virtual PC on Windows 7 x64 only able to virtualize x86 versions of Windows 7?

Comment: Which virtualisation software? Otherwise the answer is it depends on which you are using.

Comment: Oh, sorry, Virtual PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'Windows Virtual PC' for Windows 7 only emulates a Intel Pentium III, which only supported 32-bit operations, you won't be able to get an x64 version of Windows 7 to work correctly running as a guest. However you will be able to run Windows XP 64-bit as a guest but it will switch down to 32-bit operation.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Virtual_PC) on the subject adds some more information you might appreciate.

Comment: Just discovered on MSDN that there actually is an x64 version of Virtual PC 2007 as well. Maybe that will allow having x64 guests...

Comment: It won't change the emulation packing inside each VM though, so I'm still afraid you'll be out of luck - at least you'll be able to have lots of VMs with all the memory a 64-bit host will give you.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (which is free and almost 100% open source) to run a Vista x64 guest on a Windows XP 32 bit host, so I assume that it would work with Win 7 x64 on Win 7 32 bit as well.

One thing you need though: hardware assisted virtualization (ie. VT-x on Intel / Pacifica on AMD).

Comment: but VB emulates a 'better' VM environment for it's guests than VPC.